# Where to put a custom function in CakePHP

Tags: function, cakephp

I have a function in one of my views that formats data coming from the DB before displaying it.  Since I use this function in many views, I'd like to make a global function that would be accessible from every view.  How would I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, creating a helper is probably what you are looking for. See the [cookbook entry](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) for more information.

To make your helper available in all your views, add the helper to the `$helpers` array of your `AppController` (`app/Controller/AppController.php`).

Answer (score 5):

Creating a helper (as Headshota and preinheimer explained) is the best idea if the function is complex..

But if your function is simple,
you can open the file app/config/bootstrap.php

write your function in this file and that's it..

the function will be accessible anywhere (models, controllers, views, etc)

hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a view helper, here's an example one:  [Minify Helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/_k10_/2009/01/17/minify-helper-for-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create your owns View Helpers.

You will find the documentation in the Section **"View > Helpers"** of the cook book : [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)

But the section **"Core Libraries > Helpers"** just explains how to use the ready-to-use cakephp Helpers like HtmlHelper or FormHelper: [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/toc-helpers.html)

Likewise you can note that this is the same logic with firstly controllers and components, and secondly model and behaviours.

- Then the cook book presents the core components in core-libraries/toc-components
- How to create your own is explained in controllers/components
- The core behaviours are presented in core-libraries/toc-behaviors
- The how to create your own is in models/behaviours

This system is really efficient and makes cakePHP a handy framework (thank you the great documentation) that implement efficiently the Model-View-Controller design pattern.

If you understand that question correctly, you never ask yourself this kind of issue about cakePHP and by the same time, about the MVC pattern.