# how to built a function and call it everywhere in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i am newer to cakephp. i am trying to write a function which not regarding to view(function). but when i call this function resultCall to undefined function. my code is below

```
public function records(){
        $totalrec = $this->names->find('count');
        $pages = ceil($totalrec/$limit);
        return $pages;
        }
```

and call it as

```
$rowsr = records();
```

please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put a custom function in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530601/where-to-put-a-custom-function-in-cakephp)

Comment: You need to rethink your logic here, maybe you don't need that. And also `$limit` is undefined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i was searching for this.

```
$this->records();
```

this is working.
Thanks all friends.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you defining and using this function?

If you want to use it absolutely everywhere, define it in the bootstrap-file in config. But be aware that this heavily violates MVC.

Looking at the function, I would guess that you probably want to add this function to the names model. Than you can call it from the Controller this way: `$this->Names->records()` and in the model this way: `$this->records()`.